# Why isn't my JLayeredPane respecting the Z index in this method?

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

The following is a method in a "Deck" object that instantiates and manipulates an array of Card objects for various card games that I might write.  This particular method accepts a JFrame and an x and y coordinate as parameters, then creates a JLayeredPane at that location on that JFrame in order to display the cards in the deck.  Everything works well, except when it displays the cards the JLayeredPane does not respect the Z index defined by zOrd and the cards appear in the reverse order that I wish them to.

I have a JLayeredPane on the same Jframe that I am passing to this method that I placed there at design time, and I use very similar code to iterate through the deck and display them there and it works fine.  So I think there is something about my JLayeredPane that I am not doing or setting at runtime that it needs in order to respect the z index, but I can't figure out what.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    public void display(JFrame DisplayFrame, Integer x, Integer y) {
    int xPos = 0;
    int zOrd = 0;
    JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)DisplayFrame.getContentPane();
    JLayeredPane lp = new JLayeredPane();
    lp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());       
    Integer height = _cards[0].getCardImage().getHeight();
    Integer width = _cards.length * 15 + _cards[0].getCardImage().getWidth() - 15;
    lp.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    contentPane.add(lp);

    for (Card _card : _cards) {
        JLabel cardLabel = new JLabel();
        cardLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(_card.getCardImage()));
        cardLabel.setBounds(xPos, 0, _card.getCardImage().getWidth(), _card.getCardImage().getHeight());
        lp.add(cardLabel, zOrd);
        xPos+=15;
        zOrd++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `the cards appear in the reverse order that I wish them to.` - and how do you expect them to appear? We are not mind readers. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Chances are you will find the problem while creating the `SSCCE`.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  Each card is appearing beneath previous card.  I want it to appear on top of the previous card.

Comment: You should not be setting the layout of the layered pane. Don't know if this is the only problem. Read my suggestions. One of them will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer in case someone stumbles across this question in a search.

In the process of troubleshooting I wanted to add the zOrd to the text of each label to track each card's z index.  In order to do this I changed the variable type of zOrd from int to Integer so I could call the .toString() method on it.  When I did this, it worked.  At first I thought that adding text to the label was what made the difference, but it wasn't.  I removed the .setText() method and used my code exactly as written with the exception that zOrd is declared as an Integer vice an int, and it works.  To deepen the mystery, the javaDoc for the JLayeredPane.add() method even says that the parameters are supposed to be (component cmpnt, int i).

EDIT: I am new to JAVA, so to be perfectly clear, when I refer to "javaDoc" above, I am perhaps using a misnomer.  I see in writing my own classes that remarks beginning with /** placed immediately before a method with expose themselves as intellisense, at least in netbeans (perhaps other IDEs?).  So the intellisense for the add() method in the JLayeredPane object calls for (component cmpnt, int i) as parameters.  Since the intellisense is the first resource I go to for an explanation of a method and its parameters, I find this confusing.  Perhaps it is an oversight, or perhaps there is something I do not understand about this object and method.  Either way, passing it as an "Integer" works.

Things that make you go hmmmmm.

Perhaps someone very familiar with the JLayeredPane object can explain the reasoning behind this.  I certainly can't.

Comment: `the javaDoc for the JLayeredPane.add() method even says that the parameters are supposed to be (component cmpnt, int i).` - no it doesn't. JLayeredPane doesn't override the Container.add(..) method. The add(..) method is simply used for adding components to panel. It has nothing to do with layering of components. That is why I pointed you to the tutorial. The tutorial clearly uses Integer values. This is also clearly documented in the JLayeredPane API general description area.

Comment: Okay.  As I type this I am looking at netbeans.  I have an instance of the LayeredPane object with the add method awaiting parameters.  The intellisense that pops up tells me that it wants, for parameters (components cmpnt, int i).  To me, this is misleading because if I use int vice Integer it does not respect the Z index.  So that is the answer to my question.  Not "go read the tutorial."  Hopefully this answer will be helpful should anyone else ever find this confusing.  Your comments are appreciated, but my question is answered.

Comment: `To me, this is misleading` well that is your IDE, not Swing. You should understand the basics of what you are doing.  `So that is the answer to my question. Not "go read the tutorial."` - Yes, but don't expect people to spoon feed you the answer. The tutorial had a working example. I told you that lower number layers are painted first. The idea was for you to look at the tutorial to see how this was done. This is part of learning how to problem solve on your own. "Give someone a fish they eat for a day. Teach someone to fish they eat for life".

Comment: If you know the answer to my question, yes, I'd want and expect it to be spoon fed to me.  Just as I will do if I read a question to which I know the answer.  This is a support forum, man, for professionals who come to one another for knowledge they don't have, often under duress from some project or another.  Not a commune of hippies seeking your infinite zen wisdom on how to grow as a person.  You didn't know the answer, so stop waxing all condescending.  Here is something to ponder.  It irritates me how I've let you irritate me.  Will you *please* stop posting on my question.

Comment: I answer a question based on apparent effort. You didn't read the JLayeredPane API. It specifically states you use an Integer. You didn't look at the tutorial, it explicitly uses an Integer. You didn't post a SSCCE. No apparent effort was made on your part so, no, I'm not going to spoon feed the answer. `for professionals who come to one another for knowledge they don't have,` Professionals have the knowledge to look at the API first or read example code that does exactly what then want. Professionals want to know how to problem solve.

Comment: By the way, I didn't know the know the answer when I posted my suggestion so I couldn't give you the spoon fed answer. I later looked at the tutorial and API and found the exact problem in 5 minutes and determined if I could take the time to do this, then so could you.

Comment: You answer questions based on apparent effort?  LOL.  It took you 5 minutes you say to find the answer to my question, and you've spent 30 posting condescending garbage to my question.  Why then, didn't you just post the answer?  Because you didn't know it.  Do you realize that I posted my question then posted my own answer after having found it, and all of this would have happened without a word of your drivel?  You are perfectly welcome withhold your non-answers and pearls of wisdom from my posts.  I would so appreciate that.  That would take you no effort.  So would going away.  Thank you.

Comment: `You answer questions based on apparent effort?`, yes, why should I spend the time looking through your code trying to understand what you are doing when you can look at a working example and compare how your code is different with the working example? A forum is not about us spoon feeding answer, it is about pointing you in the right direction. So, I provided you with a tool to help solve your problem. Not only that you now have a reference to the tutorial that you can use for future problems.

Comment: I'm not trying to be condescending. I found the answer by following my advice. So I'm suggesting if you followed my advice you could have found the answer in 5 minutes as well instead of taking a day. Instead you took my advice as negative and used your own problem solving techniques which took longer. I'm trying to stress that learning a new concept from a working example will save time in the long run. If you then post a SSCCE based on a working example, demonstrating a problem, I will then be glad to help explain to the best of my ability, but you need to show the effort first.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for a working example. Lower numbered layers are painted before higher number layers.

Instead if using layered panes, maybe a better solution to use a layout manager that supports overlapping of components. Check out the [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) for a layout manager that supports this.

> Each card is appearing beneath previous card

```
lp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

You are not using the layered pane properly. When you use a FlowLayout, components are painted in reverse order that the component is added to a panel. Maybe you can just get rid of the set layout statement.

In any case I've given you two solutions.

Comment: Originally I did not have this line.  I added it, thinking that maybe I need to explicitly define the layout since I'm creating the JLayeredPane at runtime.  I've taken it back out.  Also, I tried decrementing the zOrd variable vice incrementing it.  Neither of those things worked.  Isn't flowlayout the default layout?

Comment: @Camenwolf, `Neither of those things worked` - The tutorial has a working example. Read the tutorial, download the example code and play with it so you understand how to use a layered pane. I can't tell you what is wrong with your code based on a few lines of code. Regarding my second suggestion to use the `Overlap Layout`, I forgot to include the link to the example code. This is a simpler solution than using a layered pane. You just use a JPanel with the custom layout. Update the answer to include the link.

Comment: I appreciate the time you are taking to read and respond to my question.  Essentially though, you are telling me to go read the tutorial and experiment until I figure it out.  I appreciate this sound advice, which can be applied to most questions asked here.  Like most people I am reading and experimenting while I periodically check this site.  I do believe that the code that I've supplied is the code that is relevant to my issue.  I am hoping that someone with a thorough understanding of the objects and methods that I'm calling will be able to answer my question based on this code.

Comment: `I do believe that the code that I've supplied is the code that is relevant to my issue.` - until the problem is solved you don't know what is or isn't relevant, which is why your were originally asked to provide a `SSCCE`. A `SSCCE` is an important problem solving tool. If you can't make an effort then why should we? You said your code worked before, so compare the working code. Not only that I provided you with a simple solution by using a custom layout that is specifically designed to do what you want.